# Ansible uri module loop on files

Tags: api, ansible, uri

I'm using the Ansible `uri` module to make a PUT API call and using all files in a directory as parameters.

I have a list of files in a directory, and I want to use the name and the content of each file in the API call

First of all i tried to list all files.

```yaml
- name: "Find pipeline files in folder"
  find:
    paths: "/app/pipelines"
    patterns: "pipeline-*.json"
    file_type: "file"
  register: pipe_files

- debug:
     var: pipe_files
```

Then I want to make a loop on each file in the directory and call the API

```yaml
- name: PUT PIPE 
  uri:
    method: PUT
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    url: "https://api_url/**FILE_NAME**"
    user: "user"
    password: "user_pass"
    body_format: json
    body: "{{ lookup('file','/app/pipelines/**FILE_NAME.json**') }}"
    validate_certs: no
    force_basic_auth: yes
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: yes
  register: pipeline_created
  until: pipeline_created.status == 200
```

When I deploy the content, I don't have the exact filename, how can I make the loop on each file to call the API?

Best regards,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`pipe_files` is a register from a find task. You can have a look at [returned values in the `find` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#return-values). You can also examine your debug task output to better get accustomed with the content of the variable.

Anyway. The list of file objects returned will be in `pipe_files.files`. Each element is a dict where the information you need is in the `path` key.

You may test with

```yaml
- name: PUT pipeline
  uri:
    method: PUT
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    url: "https://api_url/{{ item.path | basename }}" # depends on input list content
    user: "user"
    password: "user_pass"
    body_format: json
    body: "{{ lookup('file', item.path) }}" # content
    validate_certs: no
    force_basic_auth: yes
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: yes
  until: pipeline_created.status == 200
  loop: "{{ pipe_files.files }}" 
  register: pipeline_created # result will become a list
```